# write header information for csv string which should go as attachment to infopath form using javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, infopath

I am trying to achieve the functionality of converting a string to base64 encoded binary format where the encoded part needs to send to InfoPath form to display as an attachment for an attachment control in InfoPath form.

so my data will be in this format

```
"header1,header2,header3,..
 value1,value2,value3,.."
```

But the InfoPath form actual format contains below format of data

```
"filename.csvheader1,header2,header3,..
 value1,value2,value3,.."
```

so my challenge here to achieve the encoded string along with the file name attached in the encoded string.